# Dataset for Swiss (.ch) domain names with basic traffic stats

Tags: data-request, internet, switzerland

Where can I find Swiss website domains with `.ch` and with some basic stats about popularity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switch.ch publishes some stats about the top 1000 domains with `.ch`

https://www.switch.ch/open-data/

direct link to "latest" CSV file: https://www.switch.ch/open-data/top1000/latest.csv

Comment: the switch open data link is dead, but here is a method to download the CH domains: https://rimann.org/blog/listing-all-ch-domains/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @philshem already mentioned, you might also want to download the **zone file** which is available as well. With some scripting, you can extract almost all registered .ch files. Look for the lines that contain `NS` and refer to name servers, and remove duplicates. Most domain names have at least two name servers, which means as many line entries in that zone file.

A tiny percentage of registered domain names will be missing from the zone file, for instance suspended or expired domain names, or those without any name servers, and thus not resolving.

"Popularity" is a broad concept. What the registry offers is lists based mostly on the number of DNS queries which is a fairly good indicator, but it could be for E-mail or other services. Not necessarily correlated with the amount of website traffic.